# exporting csv to iOS 9 safari .. unable to read document

Tags: php, ios, csv, safari, export

I'm using php to export a csv to mobile safari.   I'm getting this error when I try to download the csv.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');

header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: must-revalidate");
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=Activity.csv");
header("Expires: 0");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed content-type to this.. solved it

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
```